# How can I list all of the users in my database based on whether a user has been marked as deleted using a Boolean of true or false;

Tags: javascript, express

I am writing a little express app using mysql database, and I have all of my routes working the way that I want them to except one.

I am trying to figure out how to write a get route that will retrieve all of the users in the database if a user is an admin based on a Boolean value true or false of whether the user has been deleted or not.

I want to list everybody who is not marked true for deleted.  When I add a where clause into the mix, I keep getting an error in my terminal that is referencing a cb that works fine until I click the delete button, and I am sure it has something to do with my where clause or possibly the whole route. I just know it works without the where in it, but I don't need to see the users marked as deleted.

My code and images are below. Thank you in advance.

```js
router.get('/usersList', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.user && req.user.Admin) {
        models.users
            .findAll({}).then(users => {
                res.render('usersList', {
                    users: users
                }, { where: { Deleted: false } });
            });
    } else {
        res.send('You are not authorized to view the users list.')
    }
});
```

`usersList.hbs`

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center">Users in the database</h1>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>View User</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th>Remove User</th>
    </tr>
    {{#each users}}
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/users/{{UserId}}">View</a></td>
      <td>{{FirstName}}</td>
      <td>{{LastName}}</td>
      <td>{{Username}}</td>
      <td>{{Email}}</td>
      <td>
        <form method="POST" action="/users/{{UserId}}">
          <button type="submit">Delete</button>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>
</div>
```

[image: Console Error]

Comment: I did not realize that my question was that bad, I apologize and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is as follows:

In the first code snippet, I have the "where" clause where it doesn't belong.

I moved the "where" clause inside of the .findAll method, using it as the criteria by which to get the list of users.  This simple fix got me the results I was trying to achieve.

usersList.js before moving the where clause.

```
router.get('/usersList', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.user && req.user.Admin) {
        models.users
            .findAll({}).then(users => {
                res.render('usersList', {
                    users: users
                }, { where: { Deleted: false } });
            });
    } else {
        res.send('You are not authorized to view the users list.')
    }
});
```

usersList.js after moving the where clause.

```
router. Get('/usersList', function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.user && req.user.admin) {
        models. Users
        .findAll({ where: { Deleted: false }})
        .then(users => {
             if(users){
               res.render('usersList', {users: users});
     } else {
         res.send('You do not have authorization to view this list');
     }
   });
  }
 });
```